# api platform: the fields of $data in _invoke method are null

Tags: rest, api, symfony, api-platform.com

I created an custom controller for the PUT operation in the User entity to encrypt the password while updating the user data.

the _invoke function :

```
 /**
 * @Route(
 *     path="/api/users/{id}",
 *     methods={"PUT"},
 *     defaults={"_api_resource_class"=User::class}
 * )
 * @param User $data
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function __invoke(User $data): JsonResponse
{
    dd($data);
    return new JsonResponse([]);
}
```

The entity User :

```
/**
* @ApiResource(
*     collectionOperations={"get"},
*     itemOperations={"get",
*     "put"={
*      "controller"=UpdateUserController::class,
*     }, "delete", "patch"}
* )
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
*/
class User implements UserInterface
{
```

But when I send a request with the new data, the fields are null and the createdAt field has the current time, it's like he try to create a new user instead of giving the one that his Id in the url path

```
^ App\Entity\User {#6197 ▼
-id: null
-email: null
-roles: []
-password: null
-firstName: null
-lastName: null
-createdAt: DateTime @1588765411 {#6196 ▼
  date: 2020-05-06 11:43:31.115062 Atlantic/Azores (+00:00)
}
```

}

Is there a proper way to receive the values in the $data argument ?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `_api_item_operation_name` in your route configuration.

> It is mandatory to set _api_resource_class and **_api_item_operation_name** (or _api_collection_operation_name for a collection operation) in the parameters of the route (defaults key). It allows API Platform to work with the Symfony routing system.

https://api-platform.com/docs/core/controllers/#alternative-method

Comment: Thank you for your response QuentinCaffeino, but I just used FOSRestBundle instead to create the api.